# Get Values from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

```
sample_dict = [{'id':123, 'name':'ABC', 'loc':'XYZ'}, {'id':456, 'name':'DEF', 'loc':'ZYX'}, {'id':789, 'name':'GHI', 'loc':'YZX'}]
```

I want to select the values of the keys ( id & name ) from the give list of dicts.

**I want a result similar to this:**

```
result = ({'id': [123, 456, 789]}, {'name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']})
```

Is there any other implementations other than the listed below. I want to achieve this with more memory efficient & less time since I have million of data to unpack. Can we achieve this with `operator.itemgetter` or `itertools`? Which will be more memory efficient and consumes less time?

**Using Dict & List Comp**

```
{'id':[i.get('id') for i in sample_dict]}

{'name':[i.get('name') for i in sample_dict]}
```

**Using Map**

```
{'id': list(map(lambda x: x.get('id'), sample_dict))}

{'name': list(map(lambda x: x.get('name'), sample_dict))}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is this:

```
for i in range(len(sample_dict)):
    print(sample_dict[i]['id'])
```

Comment: How does this answer the question & more over ```sample_dict``` is a list and above code will cause a **TypeError**

Comment: We can handle this better in Dict Comprehension

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to be simulating a database. Why not actually use a database? Or at least pandas?

Second, there's no way to iterate over 1000 items "more efficiently" as you still have to iterate over 1000 items, no matter what. Yes, itertools and itemgetter might be negligibly faster on a per-item basis, but if your problem is data size, that won't help you.

You do have to iterate the whole data set; however, you can do so once, and then have a re-usable structure. If you find yourself looping over the whole data set multiple times for different queries, this can eliminate all the duplicated work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

database = [
    {'id':123, 'name':'ABC', 'loc':'XYZ'}, 
    {'id':456, 'name':'DEF', 'loc':'ZYX'}, 
    {'id':789, 'name':'GHI', 'loc':'YZX'}]

index = defaultdict(list)
for row in database:
    for key in row:
        index[key].append(row[key])

pprint(index)
```

> defaultdict(,
>      {'id': [123, 456, 789],
>       'loc': ['XYZ', 'ZYX', 'YZX'],
>       'name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']})

Comment: Running CProfile on Dict Comprehension Way cost me 2008 calls ( Len of List * Twice)
However running CProfile on your method cost me 3006 calls ( 3 columns * Len of List ). Is there any other Specific way to target.

Comment: Also, Can you let me know will this cost memory as we are storing it in defaultdict

Comment: Then don't copy the dict - just use use the full index. I copied it just to demonstrate that it has the info. It's not supposed to build the index faster, it's supposed to avoid doing any work when you re-use it later. It has the same data as the original structure and your requested output, so it uses that much memory. However if keeping this data in memory is a hardship, you really need to use a database.

Comment: There's something you're not telling me. How do you store it? Does simple_dict exist in memory, or is that a generator?

Comment: ... because iterators make a lot more sense if you can do the work just on that part. If you have just one object from the sample_dict list in memory at a time, you don't have any issues with memory, and that's the basic point of iterators. But your original question has ALL the data in memory at the start, and ALL the data in memory for the output, so you've pretty much designed it to prevent iterators from doing their job.

Comment: I'm confused with your explanation on the itertools here. The sample_dict that I have is from a database call. I call my database and store the results on my sample_dict. And I don't want to handle this in my database as I want the same data for other operations.. I think this is more clear. Can you explain more on this frm here? Which would be the best ?

Comment: it sounds like you're not going to accept any answers that adhere to the question, but you have a working program that needs help dealing with larger data sets -- post to the code review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or look into pandas, which is probably tailor-made to what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

```
new_arr = {str:list} 
for each in sample_dict:
    for keys in each.keys():
        if keys not in new_arr.keys():
            new_arr[keys] = []
        new_arr[keys].append(each[keys])
```

output is `{'id': [123, 456, 789], 'name': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], 'loc': ['XYZ', 'ZYX', 'YZX']}`

Comment: This can be handled better by using Dict Comprehension technique mentioned above.